# Editing dataframe column values

Tags: python, pandas

My values in the totalGross column of the dataframe are as follows. I need to fix the values with ['x'] expression because I need to find the equations.

```
df['totalNet'] = df['totalNet'].map(str)
```

didn't work for me.
Thanks.

input:

```
'totalNet': ["['385.88']",'385.88',"['188.93']",'188.93',"['342.66']",'342.66',"['178.52']",'178.52',"['1947.60']",'1947.60']
```

Output :

```
0           385.88
1           385.88
2           188.93
3           188.93
4           342.66

183         422.42
184         200.00
185         200.00
186        2461.77
187        2461.77
```

Comment: Pls post your original data and your desired output

Comment: please provide the output of `df.head(10).to_dict('list')`

Comment: Are the lists actually strings too?

Comment: Name: totalNet, Length: 188, dtype: object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df['totalNet'] = pd.to_numeric(df['totalNet'].str.strip("'[]"), errors='coerce')
```

output:

```
0     385.88
1     385.88
2     188.93
3     188.93
4     342.66
5     342.66
6     178.52
7     178.52
8    1947.60
9    1947.60
Name: totalNet, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. How does it change when lists contain more than one element?

Comment: @ysmnrn.csv it depends on how you want to handle it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert `str` of `list` into `list`. In your case:

```
import ast
df['totalNet'] = ["['385.88']",'385.88',"['188.93']",'188.93', "['342.66']",'342.66',"['178.52']",'178.52',"['1947.60']",'1947.60']
df['totalNet'] = df['totalNet'].apply(lambda x: x if not x.startswith("[") else ast.literal_eval(x)[0])
df
```

Output

```
totalNet
0   385.88
1   385.88
2   188.93
3   188.93
4   342.66
5   342.66
6   178.52
7   178.52
8   1947.60
9   1947.60
```